# Linq to NHibernate: Sequence Contains no Elements

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I know I'm doing something wrong here, I just don't know what as I'm not very sure what the issue is. Here's the code which is called:

**The call**

```
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<AccountDataModel, bool>> deleg = 
                            (m => m.Email == model.Email);
                        AccountDataModel query = database.FindBy(deleg);
```

**Where the call leads to**

```
public T FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
        {
            return FilterBy(expression).Single();
        }

public IQueryable<T> FilterBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
        {
            return All().Where(expression).AsQueryable();
        }

public IQueryable<T> All()
        {
            return (from data in _session.Query<T>()
                   select data);
        }
```

**The exception thrown**

```
Sequence contains no elements
```

**Ze details**

Basically, what I'm trying to test right now is a registration module on my website which is supposed to *search* for an email which has been provided to see if it exists. I have an encrypted email address hidden in the database (and, yes, the email in the model has been encrypted as well) which is supposed to match up with the registration email provided. The problem is that no results are being returned.

What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your call to `.Single` will throw this exception when the sequence is empty. If it is possible that no matches will be found, you should use `.SingleOrDefault`, which will return `null` if no matches exist.

It's very important to Understand the differences between `Single`, `SingleOrDefault`, `First`, and `FirstOrDefault`.

Here's a helpful visualization of these methods:

```
╔═════════════════╦═════════════╦═════════╦═════════════════════╗
║                 ║ [] (Empty)  ║ ["one"] ║ ["one", "two",...]  ║
╠═════════════════╬═════════════╬═════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ FirstOrDefault  ║ null        ║ "one"   ║ "one"               ║
║ First           ║ Exception   ║ "one"   ║ "one"               ║
║ SingleOrDefault ║ null        ║ "one"   ║ Exception           ║
║ Single          ║ Exception   ║ "one"   ║ Exception           ║
╚═════════════════╩═════════════╩═════════╩═════════════════════╝
╔═════════════════╦═════════════╦═════════╦═════════════════════╗
║ Error messages: ║ no elements ║         ║ multiple elements   ║
╚═════════════════╩═════════════╩═════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

As you can see, `FirstOrDefault` is the only one that won't throw an exception.

**So, what it comes down to is this**:
The ONLY reason to use `First`, `SingleOrDefault`, or `Single`, is so that an Exception will be thrown if your results are not as you expect!
This will give you a better debugging experience, and gives your code better semantic meaning.

Comment: Thank you for responding - I changed the code to what you suggested, and I'm still receiving the same error. is there a chance I may be implementing my query improperly?

Comment: The ONLY time "Sequence contains no elements" error is thrown is when using `Single` or `First` ... it will not be thrown by `*OrDefault`.

Comment: @HollandSchutte I updated my answer with a better explanation of the different methods.  Hopefully, that will help you to find the source of your issue.

Comment: Thank you, Scott. I will review as soon as possible.